# Drupal site transfer to new host

Tags: php, drupal

I've transferred Drupal site to another hosting provider and somehow the theme looks different and I'm getting below messages when I try to log into admin by going to /user url.

```
Warning: include(/home/spankyb/public_html/sites/all/themes/siteTheme/includes/inc.mainnav.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in include() (line 10 of /home/spankyou/public_html/sites/all/themes/siteTheme/templates/page--front.tpl.php).
Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/spankyb/public_html/sites/all/themes/siteTheme/includes/inc.mainnav.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in include() (line 10 of /home/spankyou/public_html/sites/all/themes/siteTheme/templates/page--front.tpl.php).
Warning: include(/home/spankyb/public_html/sites/all/themes/siteTheme/includes/inc.spankcounter.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in include() (line 42 of /home/spankyou/public_html/sites/all/themes/siteTheme/templates/page--front.tpl.php).
Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/spankyb/public_html/sites/all/themes/siteTheme/includes/inc.spankcounter.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in include() (line 42 of /home/spankyou/public_html/sites/all/themes/siteTheme/templates/page--front.tpl.php).
Warning: include(/home/spankyb/public_html/sites/all/themes/siteTheme/includes/inc.sharingfooter.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in include() (line 56 of /home/spankyou/public_html/sites/all/themes/siteTheme/templates/page--front.tpl.php).
Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/spankyb/public_html/sites/all/themes/siteTheme/includes/inc.sharingfooter.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in include() (line 56 of /home/spankyou/public_html/sites/all/themes/siteTheme/templates/page--front.tpl.php).
```

I think I need to change /home/spankyb to spankyou

Is there a way to do this and also is there another problem that I need to fix?

Comment: r u using custom code to include the files or it's default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow following steps:

1. Empty all the cache tables manually or goto admin/settings/performance and clear cache.
2. Rebuild modules by visiting admin/build/modules
3. Rebuild themes by visiting admin/build/themes

This should fix all the errors.